# How to control randomness in MLlib Random Forest

Tags: apache-spark

When I run random forest in MLlib in Spark client mode, I noticed that even with the same random seeds, the results are different every time. I guess the root cause is that when Spark inputs the data from HDFS using `sc.textFile`, the distribution of the data to different executors are random.

Therefore, even after I fix the seeds for the random forest, the results are different since the data itself is shuffled differently every time. Is that correct? Is it possible to get the same result with the same seed? Thank you!

Comment: Some additional details would be useful but in general if you combine Spark-like architecture with FP arithmetics you typically cannot achieve full reproducibility. Since basic operations on FP numbers are neither associative nor commutative and Spark doesn't guarantee the order in which certain operations are applied the results may vary from run to run and these differences can accumulate over time. If hard to say if this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks! You are probably right that it's difficult to reproduce the results in Spark. However, that makes it difficult to tune the hyper parameters in machine learning when using Spark. If one get different results with the same setting, how can one decide which direction to go in terms of tuning the parameters? It's like shooting a moving target.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Sorting distributed structures in Spark is not stable. So it is another source of nondeterminism. Still, if differences are large enough to be a serious problem it may suggest there are some other issues out there. It can be either particular data which makes problem numerically unstable or there is some other source of randomness. How much variability are we talking about?

Comment: Good to know that sorting distributed data in Spark is not stable, which might be another reason why it's not repeatable. It may also related to the data. I have several data sets, they all have some variability. For one particular data, the difference is very significant. The recall could be two times higher from one run to the other with the same threshold. All the data sets are significantly unbalanced, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Well, unbalanced data may have an impact here. If there is a large skew then small change in the model can have unexpected large impact. But it is unlikely something that we can diagnose here. The only thing I could recommend is to analyze generated models first.